# .htaccess rewrite url don't do it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm new with htaccess configurations and I need your help.

I have this url:

**http://www.mypage.com/page/web/controller/index.php**

and I don't want to show the 
**page/web/controller/index.php**

please how can I do this?

this is my actual .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage.com$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mypage/web/
RewriteRule (.*) /page/web/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^page/web/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                            
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                            

RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.mypage.com$
RewriteRule  (.*) "http\:\/\/mypage\.com\/page\/web\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect from `http://www.mypage.com/page/web/controller/index.php` to `http://www.mypage.com` 
just add `header("location: http://www.mypage.com")` to the top of `../web/controller/index.php` and add an index.php to root directory this will redirect you to `http://www.mypage.com/index.php`.

This is not the solution you are looking for but could be an alternative solution.
And [this link may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20961274/3111913)
Thank you :)

Comment: I want a pretty Url , I don't want to delete it, I just dont want to see the big Url