# How to get URL path in PHP index file?

Tags: php, cpanel

I'm using cpanel and php to create my website.

how i can get id from url  `http://example.com/id`

problem is that when i'm trying to get url , im redirecting to file with `id` name `404` error !

and i can't get path in `index.php` page ?

for example when i try to get this url

`http://example.com/01OWUY`

i want to get `01OWUY` with

```
$link .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

code but i'm going to a 404 error

update :

every user have a id

with this id he can see her info

for example user with id `01OWUY` can see her info from database
like this ->

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

//Database connection
$conn = mysqli_connect(SERVERNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);

$user = handle_user($conn, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
?>
```

and the function is this ->

```
// Return true if link is active
function handle_user($conn, $linkId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM users WHERE link_id = '" . $linkId . "'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // get user data from db
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but i get a 404 error !!!

Comment: Try to form your question like this: Given this world... (explain the situation), When I do this...(explain what do you do), I expect this to happen...(explain what do you expect to happen).

Comment: What do you mean by "get" the id? Because what would a 404 error have to do with `$_SERVER`?

Comment: @lewis4u ok, i update my question

Comment: That means that the link `http://example.com/01OWUY` doesn't exist! Is it supposed to be there???

Comment: Kindly show your source code. You want help so show it. Trust me, it will be more clear on what you mean then your current use of programming terminology as a beginner.

Comment: @lewis4u i update my question again i hope help so this time

Comment: Did you try to debug it with var_dump($conn, $user); die(); what do you get?

Comment: when i try a path like ```http//example.com/154``` even if index page be a simple html file , i get a 404 error egain. my $conn is right becuse i test it befor .

Comment: @lewis4u but when i try URL with out id its working but ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']``` give me a ```/``` only

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. It is now clear that you want to create a "router". You will need to edit your server config file. Here may be helpful starting point on that and the rest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960877/the-basics-of-php-routing               ... Read the answers section.

Comment: And what happens when you var_dump($sql); die; inside handle_user() function

Comment: @lewis4u thank you for your question its work , and i will add a try catch in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to load index.php if the file does not exist.

this is a very common practice in php frameworks like Laravel.

#### .htaccess file

```
# Not for real file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

for this to work you must have [mod_rewrite enabled](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Then you will have the data available in your index.php file.
you will still need to [sanitize the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

---

#### Recommendation for lightweight framework includes [routing features](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#required-parameters):

## Lumen

https://lumen.laravel.com/