# Links giving 404 Not Found in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, routes

Below is my code structure

```
/public
  index.php
  about.php
  /srv
     ->srv1.php
  /solutions
     ->solution1.php
  /common
     ->header.php
     ->footer.php
  /resources
     /img
       ->img1.png
  /js
```

What I've done -->

1. included header.php & footer.php to all pages with simple include('common/header.php');
2. as a logo in header & footer included img1.png

```
<img src='resources/img/img1.png'>
```

3. Links present on header & footer

```
<a href='srv/srv1.php'>Services</a>
<a href='solutions/solution1.php'>Solutions</a>
```

Problems Facing -->

1. When I go to page srv1.php - header & footer works fine but logo (img1.png) don't show up

*I'm getting below error -->
/public/srv/resources/img/img1.png 404 NOT FOUND*

2. Even links like index.php & about.php does not work from pages srv1.php & solution1.php - same 404 error I get

**Please help with routing of links**
*Thanks in Advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960877/the-basics-of-php-routing)

But it's always good to get some framework implemented in your project.
I used CodeIgniter 4 to do the job - there present route.php file which can handle the routing of links.

There are more frameworks for php present like Laravel - use can choose whichever you want

Answer (score 0):

For me sometimes the way to solve this is adding `/`  to the start at path, for example    `<a href='/srv/srv1.php'>Services</a>`