# Create a "temporary" page [slug].php from a slug recovered on an API

Tags: php

I use an API that retrieves information about drinks. Users can use a search bar to search for the drinks they want. When they type for example "Vodka" there are 2 results: "Vodka" and "Vodka Orange". I want that for each drink my code creates a "temporary" URL [slug].php with the slug of the drink that I get with my api example if they click on Vodka Orange it generates the page "vodka-orange.php". But I don't want the pages to register on my site, because I have more than 10.000 drinks.

Example of my code:

```
<a href="<?php print_r($obj['drinks'][0]['slug']);?>.php"><?php print_r($obj['drinks'][0]['title']); ?></a> ?>
```

I don't know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is what a database and a routing engine is for

Comment: Something like `drink.php?drink=Vodka` wouldn't work for you?

Comment: File extensions are generally used to indicate how a file is intended to be used/read. If you don't want the file to exist on disk, and I'm fairly certain advertising that PHP is involved in this to users (search engines, humans, etc.), is there a specific reason that you want it to have an extension? Most question of a similar nature on this site are actually people trying to hide the server-side extension.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I don't specifically want something like "vodka.php" if there is another solution I would like. But I want to be able to have the same page for all drinks but with different data (the data of the drink the user is looking for) in this page

Comment: As noted above, just look into routing. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20961274/231316) has a very nice top-level overview of it. The general idea is that you (basically) override the web server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc.) 404 function and say "if you can't serve a file, let my PHP code try instead". There's tons of lightweight frameworks out there or you can pretty easily roll your own.